# How to add Zeros where observations are missing

Tags: r, missing-data

Here's an example of some data that I have

```
 dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", 
"i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "b", 
"c", "d", "e", "f", "j", "k", "n", "m", "q", "r"), Number = c(1, 
2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), Location = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2), Surveyor = c("JKK", "JKK", "JKK", "JKK", "JKK", "JKK", 
"JKK", "JKK", "JKK", "JKK", "JKK", "JKK", "JKK", "JKK", "JKK", 
"JKK", "JKK", "JKK", "JKK", "JKK", "JKK", "JKK", "JKK", "JKK", 
"JKK", "JKK", "JKK", "JKK", "JKK", "JKK", "JKK")), row.names = c(NA, 
-31L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Number = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Location = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Surveyor = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x00000253510611f0>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

In the above example I have the col `ID` which contains the letters a-t (my real data have other letter codes), in `Location` 1 all of these codes are present. However in `Location` 2 some of them are missing.

I would like to add `0` into the `Number` col where there are missing IDs.

My real data has 25 locations so ideally I'd like to be able to grab the full list of IDs and check that against each Location and add 0 where they are missing.

I've tried `tidyverse::mutate` with `case_when` but I'm not getting anywhere. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`tidyr::complete()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/complete.html) for this. The `fill` parameter allows you to set the values in the columns you create.

```r
df  |> 
    tidyr::complete(
        ID,
        Location, 
        fill = list(Number = 0)
    )
```

For the new values, the output will have `0` for `Number` and `NA` for any columns not explicitly set, i.e. `Surveyor`.

#### Output

I assigned the above to a variable called `new_df` so you can easily compare with the original `df`:

```r
dplyr::anti_join(new_df, df, by = c("ID", "Location"))

# A tibble: 9 × 4
  ID    Location Number Surveyor
  <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>   
1 a            2      0 NA      
2 g            2      0 NA      
3 h            2      0 NA      
4 i            2      0 NA      
5 l            2      0 NA      
6 o            2      0 NA      
7 p            2      0 NA      
8 s            2      0 NA      
9 t            2      0 NA
```

Comment: Ok I guess this is more complicated than I thought. I would like to fill in all the other info too, I have more col names than shown here so it will require a better question I think.

Comment: @McMahok Now that this question has been answered, I'd suggest asking a new one rather than editing in substantial changes.